# How to set the Exchange of a bean to ProducerTemplate

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

i m running a test with CamelTestSupport,

```
public class TestIntegrationBeanCtrlContrat extends CamelTestSupport {

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
protected ProducerTemplate template;

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
          this.from("direct:start")
         .bean(MyClassA.class, "methodOfMyClassA").to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}
@Test
public void test_ControleBean_Integration() {
    this.template.sendBody(....);

 }
```

I m trying to put the body of another bean to the producer template , for exemple :

```
template.sendBody( bean(MyClassB.class, "methodOfMyClassB") )
```

Is it possible to do that ?

In general How can i do to setup the input in the produceTemplace.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure I understand your needs but if you want to inject the result of some bean in the route process you should use Camel Mock to inject the bean process (MyClassB.methodOfMyClassB() in your example):

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
protected ProducerTemplate template;

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start").bean("BeanA", "methodA").to("mock:beanB").to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:beanB");
    mock.whenAnyExchangeReceived(new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // call the method of your class here
            exchange.getIn().setBody(MyClassB.methodOfMyClassB());
        }
    });
    template.sendBody("Your message body...");

    // check some results
    mock.assertIsSatisfied();
}
```

Comment: Thxs, but how can i call MyClassB.methodOfMyClassB at this line ,"  exchange.getIn().setBody(MyClassB.methodOfMyClassB());" , because MyClassB contains a method methodOfMyClassB with final Exchange exchange as a parameter.